# JAVA стринги в отдельный класс

Tags: java, строки

Пытаюсь вынести все `String` в отдельный `public` класс, компилятор против, как его уговорить? Мои тексты для пользователя довольно длинные, если их убрать из класса `main`, то код не будет перегружен лишним текстом и станет читабельней?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(hello);
    System.out.println(w_up);
    System.out.println(bye);
    }

public class stingsStore{
String hello = "Здравствуйте дорогие друзья";
String w_up = "Очень рад, бла-бла-бла. Как поживаете?";
String bye = "Ну всё пока, потом ещё куча текста...";
}
```

Спасибо.

Comment: сделайте все `public static final String` .

Comment: сделал, не принимает. В классе main  не может определить переменную " hello cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: В классе  stringStore тоже не всё ок. "Syntax error on token 'final' , interface expected after this token"

Comment: Потому как ваша  hello определена внутри класса stringstore то и вызывать ее надо как (new stringstore() ). hello

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Класс с переменными объявляется так:

```
public class StringsStore {
    public static final String hello = "Здравствуйте дорогие друзья";
    public static final String w_up = "Очень рад, бла-бла-бла. Как поживаете?";
    public static final String bye = "Ну всё пока, потом ещё куча текста...";
}
```

Далее, использование:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StringsStore.hello);
    System.out.println(StringsStore.w_up);
    System.out.println(StringsStore.bye);
}
```

Можно так же применить `import static`:

```
import static StringsStore.hello;
import static StringsStore.w_up;
import static StringsStore.bye;
//Или импортировать все поля класса
//import static StringsStore.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hello);
    System.out.println(w_up);
    System.out.println(bye);
}
```

Comment: очень смело по поводу 1.7+

Comment: Спасибо, это очень развернутый и понятный ответ.

Comment: ну так то статические импорты появились в 1.5 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Если StringsStore сделать интерфейсом, то можно просто имплементировать его где нужно и будут доступны все константы. Это как вариант.

Answer (score 16):

Используйте стандартные джава Properties. Поместите все ваши строки с какими нибудь ключами в файл `messages.properties` и потом используйте `ResourceBundle`  чтобы получить значение строки по ключу. Например имея:

messages.properties

```
hello = Здравствуйте дорогие друзья
w_up = Очень рад, бла-бла-бла. Как поживаете?
bye = Ну всё пока, потом ещё куча текста...
```

Для того чтобы получить 'hello' строку

```
String basename = "messages";
ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename).getString("hello");
```

Конечно такое решение выглядит сложнее чем строковые константы, но позволяет отделить содержание текстов от кода, также вы потом можете перевести строки на другой язык когда выйдете на международный рынок. Да, еще, пропертис поддерживают многострочные данные.

Comment: Это  вы советуете для AndroidStudio? Не для  Eclipse, верно?

Comment: Для эклипса тоже будет работать

Answer (score 4):

Сделайте строки статичными и они будут доступны с любого места

```
public static final String
```

Answer (score 3):

Для вывода сообщения лучше реализовывать отдельный класс или метод.

```
public  class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PrintText print = new PrintText;
        print.print();
    }
}

class PrintText {
    private String hello = "Здравствуйте дорогие друзья";
    private String w_up = "Очень рад, бла-бла-бла. Как поживаете?";
    private String bye = "Ну всё пока, потом ещё куча текста...";

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(hello);
        System.out.println(w_up);
        System.out.println(bye);
    }

}
```

Comment: Это в случае если я должен вывести все строки за раз, так сказать пакетом. А если только там где мне необходимо и только то что нужно?

Comment: Просnо создаете переменную, например, в методе final String str = "somestr"; И вызываете метод System.out.println(str);

Либо в том же классе создать строку как private final String (private static final String), если метод, в котором используется строка, не static. Или private static final String, если метод - static;